# How similar are Ukrainian and Russian?

Tags: comparative-linguistics, russian, ukrainian

How similar are the [Ukrainian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukrainian_language) and [Russian languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_language)? For example, can I reasonably expect that anybody from Ukraine would be able to understand spoken Russian or be able to read a Russian text?

Comment: This is my first question on this site - and I would not be surprised if it remains the only question I ask here. I am not really familiar with the [linguistics.se] site - so my apologies if the question is off-topic or if I chose unsuitable tags.

Comment: As a native Ukrainian speaker, I understand Russian as well as my own native language.

Comment: Nitpick: Linguistic similarity and whether a native of country A could understand something spoken or written in language B are not really the same thing. For example, many countries either currently have or historically had specific foreign languages as either mandatory or widely taken optional courses in their primary or secondary education systems, so people from those countries are likely to have basic proficiency in those languages despite them not being similar to their native languages (see for example English in Japan or Swedish in Finland).

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn Yes, that is certainly true - and I can confirm it from my own experience.  I was born in [Czechoslovakia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Czechoslovakia) and I was ten when it was dissolved. So I have heard Czech language often on TV and a bit in everyday life, too. And many books and newspapers were available in Czech.  I can understand Czech without any problem. But I have heard from several people that this is more difficult for younger people, who were already born after we become two separate states.

Comment: Even as a Czech speaker with only basics of Russian and true basics of Polish from online learning I am able to understand Ukrainian as well as Russian if not better. There are some clear similarities to Polish - both lexical and phonetic. Overall, Ukrainian is clearly closer to West Slavic than Russian.

Comment: I see some asymmetry in your question, why not asking if "anybody from Russia would be able to understand spoken Ukrainian or be able to read a Ukrainian text?" Bad connotation.

Comment: I am Bulgarian (Bulgarian language is also "slavonic") and I am somewhat fluent in Russian. It took me 2-3 weeks of reading news in Ukrainian to fully adapt to its subtleties.

Comment: This might be an interesting read for you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_language_in_Ukraine

Comment: @fraxinus, I know neither Ukrainian nor Russian but find that hearing sentences in both languages usually I'm able to figure out what is the meaning. Knowing both Bulgarian and Russian is not a fair comparison :)

Comment: @akostadinov in fact, it is about knowing few Bulgarian dialects from the present Bulgarian teritory. These dialects pretty much cover the basic lexical content of both languages in question (and even some of the grammar if one considers western border-bound Bulgarian speeches). Both Russian and Ukrainian can be considered feature-frozen old versions of Bulgarian.

Comment: @vitaliy125 now the question is still - and I will assume your family background is also 100% ethnic Ukrainian - did you learn Russian in some way (e.g. watching cartoons on TV/Youtube in Russian) or is your background such that you are saying you were able to understand Russian without prior exposure to it, merely from knowing Ukrainian (I consider this fully possible, btw. Just curious.).

Comment: @fraxinus: I think I remember most linguists consider Bulgarian to be closer to Church Slavonic and through that Old Slavonic than either Russian or Ukrainian. You seem to see it exactly the other way around?! But then, I've met Bulgarians who have argued that certain grammatical features of Bulgarian put it closer to Persian than to other Slavonic languages.

Comment: @0xC0000022L the issue is pretty much politically loaded in the last century or two. The whole "slavonic" theme is more of a Russia-originated political doctrine than a pure scientific concept. The "Church slavonic" sounds to an ordinary Bulgarian as Russian... because of the case suffixes. Lexically and historically, it is Bulgarian - the language Bulgarians did speak everyday, some time back. In the ottoman period, Bulgarian lost its cases almost completely in order to form the modern official Bulgarian. Dialects, on the other hand, still keep different cases in different areas.

Comment: @fraxinus interesting, thanks for the response! Much appreciated. I wasn't aware of the connotation you allege for "Slavonic", but I'll keep it in mind. Whenever I heard it, it was purely in a linguistic or historical sense. However, I am aware that Russian (or shall we say Soviet?!) linguists have had a big say over decades in how to interpret the relations among the various Slavic/Slavonic languages and had applied a somewhat Russo-centric view to the whole affair.

Answer (score 28):

Ukrainian and Russian are partially mutual intelligible. I as a native Russian speaker can read Ukrainian and usually understand the most but spoken Ukrainian is relatively hard to understand, although partly it is clear too.

Both Russian and Ukrainian are East Slavic languages. The closest language to Russian is considered Belarusian (also an East Slavic language) and therefore Ukrainian is probably the second closest language.

As far as I know there are lots of native Russian speakers in Ukraine who are usually bilingual and given the history of Ukraine and the current political context it's reasonable to assume that Ukrainians generally tend to know Russian better than Russians know Ukrainian because there's virtually no use in knowing Ukrainian in Russia. However, being fluent in Russian in Ukraine is fairly important, for example, as other answers stated, even current Ukrainian president is bilingual which I think is of use for him.

That being said, I think Ukrainians shouldn't have any problems with acquiring Russian quick enough even those who haven't already learned Russian.

Comment: Given the history of Ukraine and the relative size of the two languages internationally (and in terms of number of speakers), I would expect that Ukrainians generally have better Russian skills than Russians have Ukrainian skills.

Comment: Plus, there's a significant Russian-speaking minority in Ukraine, and they don't all live in the east. President Zelensky is a bilingual native speaker.

Comment: As far as I can tell, yes, while there's a lot of Russian native speakers in Ukraine who are usually bilingual there is virtually no primarily Russian speakers living in Russia who are truly fluent in Ukranian although we basically can understand Ukranian as I stated in my answer. In Russia there's about no real use in knowing Ukranian so Ukranians living in Russia probably lose their language with time. That being said I think Ukrainian speakers from actual Ukraine shouldn't have any problems with acquiring Russian quickly enough even if they haven't yet learned it to a certain degree.

Comment: Perhaps a different question, but coming from a native American English speaker - is Ukrainian/Russian similar to the differences in British and American English? (Where it's primarily spelling/pronunciation, but same alphabet and general rules)? Or is it more complex than that?

Comment: @BruceWayne English is unusual in that it has very few other languages that are a short lexical distance from it.  The closest comparison might be Scots, which is barely intelligible as you can see in the examples here:  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scots_language

Comment: @Mike yeah that was my worry (English is tough to compare like this). So Ukr/Rus is close lexically and there's no real example of two English "languages"? That's what I was assuming.

Comment: @BruceWayne "Close lexically" is also a somewhat loose description when already the alphabets differ noticably:Ukrainian cyrillic alphabet has Ґ, Є, І, Ї, whereas Russian cyrillic has Ё, Ы, Э (and recently seems to have a tendency to add V and Z)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen The writing system and the orthography are only accidental and not a core feature of a language. Lexical closeness is measured by the rate of cognates in a given set of basic words, allowing for some sound shifts.

Comment: Although this is a guess from my side, but I actually think there are quite some Ukrainian people that are more fluent in Russian than in Ukrainian. I at least know some Ukrainians that prefer speaking Russian with each other over Ukrainian, so they might actually know it better. As far as I know their school is in Ukrainian and any official stuff, but day to day life and speaking and writing among friends and family happens in Russian. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_language_in_Ukraine

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: The differences in alphabet are virtually irrelevant — e.g. Swedish and Norwegian use different alphabets (*ä, ö* vs *æ, ø*), but are mostly mutually intelligible and very lexically close.

Comment: @BruceWayne The best comparison is probably something like Jamaican Patois (in intelligibility not history), although it's more intelligible spoken than written, try sounding out this "Wi Faada we iina evn, mek piipl av nof rispek fi yu an yu niem. Mek di taim kom wen yu ruul iina evri wie." and you can probably guess what it is a translation of even if it seems initially bizarre.

Comment: @JackAidley I'd say Ukrainian vs Russian difference is kinda like English vs Scots as Mike already pointed out in comments. Some words are the same, some are similar and some are unclear but usually guessable and the spelling system is only slightly different. Russian speakers often feel about Ukrainian like it is funny because it sounds like a parody on Russian language.

Answer (score 19):

The mutual intelligibility of the Slavic languages (going far beyond the pair Ukrainian and Russian) is a fascinating theme for [linguistic research](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/29994/9781), and there are works out there trying to measure the distances, e.g., in terms of [lexical distance](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/3007/9781).

A more difficult question is the psychological one: Does a potentially traumatized Ukrainian person want to be addressed in Russian? It may be worth trying any other common language than Russian before switching over to Russian as language of intercommunication. Some person may have strong feelings in this respect, others not.

Comment: I don't think there is a psychological barier here (at least, for most people). There is virtually no stigma over the Russian _language_ in Ukraine. There is a great deal of Ukraine where a mixture of the two languages is used in everyday life. A lot of Ukrainan people are fluent only in Russian (without those people being less Ukrainian in other regards). Judging from the torrent of videos from Ukraine now, pure Russian is sometimes used even between Ukrainian military personnel.

Comment: +1 for the very relevant first paragraph — but the second paragraph seems like just projecting reactions onto people.  Do you have any sources of Ukrainians suggesting anything like that?  As other comments+answers mention, plenty of Ukrainians speak Russian as either L1 or an everyday L2 — indeed, portraying Russian-speaking as implying allegiance to Russia has been part of *Putin’s* propaganda line.

Comment: I can tell you that customs officers on the Polish/Ukrainian border in 2000/2001 had little interest in communicating in Russian until they had received a bribe. First hand experience; but may no longer be true. But back in the day in the parts of Ukraine that I lived in temporarily the language in daily use was Russian with a Ukrainian accent (e.g. г being frequently pronounced as in Ukrainian, but using Russian sentences) and there were no huge animosities between Russians from RU, ethnic Ukrainians in UA or ethnic Russians in UA. In fact many families are/were mixed ethnicity.

Comment: When I visited Kiev at the end of last year, half people were only-Russian speaking. There are a lot of refugees in my city nowadays, I observe all of them mostly speaking Russian. So there is no stigma about it. But I heard some people that didn't speak Ukrainian in the past, starting to use it more.

Comment: Of course, not. Even Ukrainian President's office speakers make daily streams in Russian. Russian is the most spoken language in Ukrainian capital city, Kiev.

Answer (score 19):

You have 2 questions in 1:

- How mutually intelligible the 2 languages are.
- What's more practical to help refugees.

In terms of mutual intelligibility, it highly depends on context, an educated (the English equivalent would be having studied Chaucer/Shakespeare in English lit in high school, because a lot of Ukranian words are very similar to old Russian words, that aren't in common use anymore, but would be recognizable to someone who'd encountered them in literature) Russian speaker needs to spend a day to learn to listen to vowel shifts and the different inflections + learn ~150 truly different common words to comfortably follow e.g. Ukranian popular political speeches, debates on talk-shows, etc. because those are aimed towards the masses and use simple language as well as using a bunch of the same foreign loan-words(inflation, corruption, computerization, etc.). A high-school dropout in a specialized setting would really struggle. Conversely if he was with Ukranian high school dropouts, he would probably be OK, since the swearing is identical.

In terms of what's practical to learn to serve refugees, definitely Russian.
To get a sense of what language people from different regions use day-day, check out Google Trends and compare different Russian vs Ukranian terms for searches within Ukraine. Here are a couple of examples (last 12 months):
[Kyiv/Kiev](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?geo=UA&q=%D0%9A%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B2,%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%97%D0%B2): 13% Kyiv/87% Kiev
[Cheap tickets](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?geo=UA&q=%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B,%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%96%20%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8): 18% Ukrainian
Note that Google counts Crimea and the separatist regions as part of Ukraine for this purpose, so accounting for population, add ~4% to the Ukrainian total.

Interestingly enough, even the result for [Russian aggression](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=today%201-m&geo=UA&q=%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F,%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%96%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%96%D1%8F) in the last 30 days, is only 39% Ukrainian.

Even Poroshenko and Zelensky are native Russian speakers who learned Ukrainian to enter politics. Here's a video of Zelensky using his gym time to learn Ukrainian, 3 months before he was elected president: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PohoNwCDOFk
And Poroshenko had several infamous lapses, when he forgot the Ukrainian word for something and had to ask his aides, e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y57R2ldt8P4 He's asking his aide how to say wallet in Ukrainian.

Also note that refugees are more likely to be from the Russian speaking east.
Here's today's [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mkp1AR5xEjk&t=390s) of Ukrainian ultra-nationalist politician Iryna Farion complaining that of the Ukrainian refugees in Poland, 80% are speaking Russian in the streets and the Poles are worried that now Putin will have an excuse to invade to protect Russian speakers in Poland. Now, Farion is an extremist and is probably hyperbolizing, but this is an amusing data-point I thought I'd include.

Comment: Do you have a source for Poroshenko being a native Russian speaker?

Comment: @Džuris you don't remember words better in а foreign language than your own. Also, he was one of the founders of the "Pro Russian" Party of the regions, before he had a falling out and switched to supporting the nationalist Yushenko. That's when he started speaking Ukrainian in public. In private, according to telephone calls leaked by Kolomoisky, to get back at Poroshenko taking PrivatBank away from him: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gAfQrwN1tKo he still speaks Russian in private(The embarrassment of the call is how much he's swearing, not the language, which surprised nobody).

Comment: @Eugene while I can only provide anecdotal evidence from myself and my surroundings, "you don't remember words better in а foreign language than your own" is not necessarily true, especially for those that don't use their native language much (expats etc), or actively use another language as much as their native language (people who work in a workplace that doesn't use the country's language etc).

Comment: @ave doesn't that pretty much drive home the point Eugene was making? I know several Ukrainians who have mixed ethnicity background (one parent from Russian SSR, another from Ukrainian SSR). They'd probably consider both language native. Obviously in younger people this will be different, since the independence of 1994. They will probably consider themselves simply Ukrainian. The sense of being Ukrainian did exist when I temporarily lived there in 2000/2001, but it didn't have the same nationalistic connotations that crept in later.

Comment: @ave, yes if you've emigrated to a foreign country, you can certainly forget words in your native language, but if you're the president of a country where it's the only official language(certainly in your workplace), use it every day publicly and have made it one of the 3 core tennets of your political dogma(along with the army and church), the only way you can forget basic day to day words, is if it's not your native language.

Comment: @Eugene Yes, I think the key word here is _immersion_. I.e. whether or not you are immersed in the language in question.

Comment: If Russian is actually preferred by the vast majority of Ukrainians (80% ?!), how come it's not the official language of Ukraine? Is it possible that Google users are just choosing Russian to get better or more search results?

Comment: @MWB it's always been a political act, to say that: "we're not Russian". Since the Russian speakers in Ukraine could always understand Ukrainian, it was practical, in a way that e.g. making Irish the only official language of Ireland wouldn't be. Apart from Zelensky and Poroshenko learning Ukrainian very late in life,  a ton of prominent politicians are in that boat, e.g. Kiltchko and there are some like Avakov and Kolomoysky that still haven't, but that hasn't stopped them from being anti Russian.

Comment: "you don't remember words better in а foreign language than your own": frequently, I do.  If you're exposed to a given concept more frequently in the foreign language, you're likely to remember the foreign word more readily.

Comment: @phoog for complex technical concepts, yes, that can happen, but there's no way that Poroshenko was exposed to the concept of "wallet" way more in Russian than Ukrainian, if he was a native Ukrainian speaker.

Comment: @Eugene not only for complex technical concepts.  When I lived in Amsterdam and almost all of my friends were, like me, native English speakers, we began adopting Dutch words.  Some, like _fiets,_ were mostly affectation, but frequently the Dutch word would just be the first one to come to mind and, knowing that the listener would understand it, I'd stop searching for the English word and just say, for example, _broodje._  But yeah, I wouldn't have needed to ask someone else for the word "sandwich"; I'd just have needed to think for another second or so.

Comment: @phoog you're describing your experience as a foreign immigrant. I can see how that could happen. Poroshenko forgot "wallet(and others, I only included one of several examples in the answer), while president of his native country, while championing that language as his #1 political priority.

Comment: *"~150 truly different common words"* -- Is "wallet" one of them? I'm curious if there is a list somewhere? How could Poroshenko fail to memorize 150 words in his prep for presidency?

Comment: @MWB I said about 150 truly different words to comfortably follow Political speeches and debates on TV talk shows(muuuch bigger in Ukraine and Russia than in the US). This is my experience, I started watching in 2014, to see both sides, it took me a couple days, pausing to look up what I didn't understand. Politicians use simple language for mass appeal, lots of common loan words like reform, computerization, etc. are easy to follow. Some words like wallet in that example, can be parsed from it's parts and understood by a Russian speaker, but understanding vs recall is different

Comment: @MWB for an easily understandable example of words that can be easily understood, but not recalled, in Russian, a helicopter is "vertical flyer", while in Ukrainian, it's "Screw wing"(It also used to be vertical flyer, but was officially changed to be different) A native Russian speaker would have zero issues immediately understanding what's meant when a screw-wing was shot down, but not be able to recall what to call it, if they were trying to speak Ukrainian.

Comment: @MWB so the number of words that are so different they can't be understood by parsing their root and modifier, or their similarity to archaic Russian words, is ~150 for "mainstream" understanding, more for specialized contexts. E g. Ukrainian legalese is in the WTF category for a Russian speaker ( but any legalese is tough, even for natives) But for a native Russian speaker to speak Ukrainian fluently, even in politicianese, is much harder, as Poroshenko has demonstrated on multiple occasions.

Comment: I did a bit of Googling, and people are saying that while Zelensky speaks Ukrainian with a foreign accent, Poroshenko does not -- he might have something of a regional accent. I can see how he might be natively bilingual, yet not used to talking about his wallet in Ukrainian, and that's why he was at a loss for words in that instance.

Comment: @MWB Zelensky certainly has a Russian accent, it's obvious in sounds like Zh. As for Poroshenko, after your comment, I watched his speeches and while he doesn't have the obvious tells now, in his old speeches just after he broke with the Party of the regions 22y ago, re-invented himself as a Ukrainian nationalist and started speaking Ukrainian in public, he has those tells. I think it's more likely that he's simply had way longer to work with an accent coach at being authentic, unlike Zelensky, who only learned Ukrainian 5y ago and didn't need to be authentically Ukrainian as his image.

Answer (score 14):

Russian and Ukranian are mutually intelligeable to a significant degree... perhaps to greater extent than, e.g., French and Italian. However, it is necessary to keep in mind that the situation with understanding is not quite symmetric here:

**Ukrainians speaking/understanding Russian**
Russian was *lingua franca* in the USSR and before that in the Russian Empire. Thus, everyone in Ukraine, above certain age, speaks perfect Russian. Moreover, Ukraine had been tied to Russia for much longer than other Soviet subjects, and the two cultures intertwine - e.g., Gogol, Shevchenko, and Babel have been considered classical Russian writers and studied in Russian schools (or at least were studied in the Soviet period). Thus, one hardly could expect here a situation where the post-Soviet generation wouldn't speak Russian - as is the case, e.g., in the Baltic countries. Indeed, in post-Soviet Ukraine one could often see television programs where different participants would speak Ukrainian and Russian - depending on their background - and understand each other. Abroad, until recently, Ukrainians would freely mingle with Russians, and largely treated as "Russians" (often the blanket term for anyone coming from the USSR area). Given large Russian-speaking communities in Europe, United States and Israel, as well as in the former parts of the Soviet Union, Ukrainians will certainly find being able to speak Russian helpful. **Certainly, some Ukrainians would be too traumatized to speak Russian... but it is more reasonable to expect that Ukrainians would be much more attuned to the difference between *Russian, Russians, Russia and Putin* than the non-Russian inhabitants of the hosting countries.**

**Russians speaking/understanding Ukrainian**
The situation is not reciprocal, as few Russians, beyond professional linguists, have ever had need to study Ukrainian - even those living in Ukraine could perfectly survive speaking Russian. This was one of the reasons for the resentment against the [Ukrainization policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukrainization#Post-1991:_Independent_Ukraine) in post-Soviet Ukraine. The political developments of the last decade however have triggered interest in studying the language among the Russian speakers outside Ukraine... notably in Russia.

Comment: I agree regarding "the need", but I think those who have - for example - had contact with Church Slavonic texts or another Slavonic language in general will have an easier time comprehending Ukrainian. In spoken language it's a number of words that are different and there are some vowel shifts, I think (e.g. Kharkov/Kharkiv) as well as the pronunciation. As a non-native speaker (to any Slavonic language) I've also discovered "cheats" like Polish ę often corresponding to у in Russian/Ukrainian (ręka). I imagine similar "cheats" can easily be discovered by Russian speakers regarding Ukrainian.

Comment: @0xC0000022L I wonder how valid is your cheat. The actual predecessor of the Polish ę is the Proto-Slavic ę and that developed into ja (я) in East Slavic. And hence pjať vs. pięć or dziesięć vs. desjať and similar. It is a bit more complicated with the merge of the ę and ǫ nasals and then split into ę and ą, but that is the main equivalent. A more valid cheat would be the Russian ě, when descended from yat, be i in Ukrainian and ie/ia in Polish. белый бедный бес в лес  => білий бідний біс у ліс => biedny biały bies w les

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава one thing I have learned with those cheats is, that they aren't universal. But it has helped me sometimes "decode" the meaning of a word which at its face was unknown at first. But again, just like with French/Spanish you can also find yourself stumped when you realize that your rule of thumb falls apart. Going by your screen name you are probably native speaker of _some_ Slavonic_ language and taking your arguments you probably know more than the average speaker. I don't know enough about the vowel shifts across Slavonic languages for any _serious_ argument. I cheat 

Answer (score 5):

Nearly all Ukrainians understand and speak Russian fluently, even from the west of the country (Lviv, Ivano-Frankovsk regions). This is not because the languages are similar but because Russian was the state language in the USSR, and remains an important language of international communication (it is second only to English in the Internet for instance).

If you go to Moldova or Kazakhstan, you will find that a lot of people there also speak Russian, despite the fact that their languages are not as closely related to Russian as Ukrainian is.

On the other hand, Russians have troubles understanding Ukrainian. [Here is an interview](https://youtu.be/upunVLhIVPc?t=1396), made about a week ago, of former Polish president Kwasniewski to an Ukrainian journalist Dmitry Gordon (in Russian), where he tells a story (the link is with timecode) of him being with Putin invited to a celebration of a 10 years jubilee of Ukrainian independence in 2001.

Everybody was speaking Ukrainian on the party. He tells that Putin asked him "How much (of Ukrainian) do you understand?". Kwasniewski replied "about 90%". Putin said "but I understand only 30%". Kwasniewski of course could use advantage of knowing both Polish and Russian.